# How to force open and closing tags in XML transform?

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi I have a transform where I'm trying to create a static element where the open and closing tags persist in the output.

For example, I've tried...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<root>
<child>
<!--static values-->
<xsl:element name="ad_version"></xsl:element>
<action_code></action_code>
</child>
</root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This outputs the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<root>
  <child>
    <ad_version />
    <action_code />
  </child>
</root>
```

I need...

```
<ad_version></ad_version>
<action_code></action_code>
```

Thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't mind having comment tags between you could cheat by adding `<xsl:comment />` or `<!---->` between the open and close tags... I'd hoped the same would work with `<xsl:text />`, but no joy...

Comment: ps. Why do you need to do this?  Technically the two forms are identical; so in most cases you'd want the option with the least characters / that's what your XSLT engine's trying to give you... Perhaps there's another way to solve your underlying issue (i.e. this may be an XY problem: http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: The vendor that is accepting the feed from me is balking when it outputs the combined element tag.  They say it's not valid though it passes every validator I've used.  And, the parsing engine outputs it that way regardless of how I pass it.  I did just try with creating <xsl:text> using the following and it seems to work.  It's messy though.

    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;ad_version&gt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/ad_version&gt;</xsl:text>

Comment: Tell that vendor that they need to follow XML standards.  If you're the customer, they have even more reason to follow standards.  Seriously, I'd force the issue, don't let some Excel jockey tell you what valid XML is or isn't..

Comment: Found a hack that seems to work; change your output from `xml` to `html`.  `<xsl:output method="html"` ... `/>`; or better yet to `xhtml` to keep the XML header.  See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rMR/1

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags

Comment: Thanks for your help on this.  I think all of these would work.  Using an empty value-of worked and seems to be the cleanest of all.

Comment: Formatting XML in a particular way for people who don't parse XML properly is a perennial StackOverflow problem; we also see the other side of the coin of people who insist on parsing XML using home-brew parsers that will cause such problems for anyone generating the XML. Would you bend an electrical plug to fit in a mis-shapen socket? Hopefully not. It's shoddy, bad engineering and you should insist on conformance to standards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Officially there's no difference between empty (`<a></a>`) and atomic (`<a />`) tags; so your vendor has a bug if they can't accept this data / really it should be on them to fix since they're not standards compliant.

However, if you have to hack your code to match their standards, there are ways...

- If you're using Microsoft's .Net **XslCompiledTransform** you can populate the tags with `<xsl:value-of select="''" />`; i.e. code which outputs blank at runtime.  See [XSLT Fiddle Example](http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rMR/2)
- If you're using **Saxon**, you can switch the output from `xml` to `xhtml`, e.g. `<xsl:output method="xhtml"`.  See [XSLT Fiddle Example](http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rMR/1).

For other engines, let us know and we can try to find a hack.  For many changing the output to `html` would likely work, but would lose the XML Declaration (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`), so can cause other issues, especially if you're using characters outside of the normal ASCII range.

Comment: I've tried pushing back.  I'm not making any headway with them.  even sent them proof of it being valid etc.  I don't know what they're using as a parser.    Thank you very much.

I'm using .Net.  That worked by using <xsl:value-of select="''" />..