# XSLT empty XML value removes parent end tag

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a problem with XSL transformation. I have a code:

```
<span class="A"> <xsl:value-of select="FIELD_A" /> </span>
<span class="B"> <xsl:value-of select="FIELD_B" /> </span>
```

The output of the above code when values are present is correct:

```
<span class="A"> VALUE A </span>
<span class="B"> VALUE B </span>
```

The problem is when some values are missing. If `FIELD_A` is empty then output HTML is:

```
<span class="A" />
<span class="B"> VALUE B </span>
```

and my browser creates:

```
<span class="A">
     <span class="B"> VALUE B </span>
</span>
```

This is a header of my xslt file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-2" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Any ideas why end tag of that span is removed and how can I fix that?

Comment: So is it a HTML parsing problem in a particular browser? Which browser exactly? Do you run the XSLT in the browser or on the server? Which `xsl:output` method exactly do you use, how does the HTML result the XSLT processor outputs look exactly, before "your" browser manipulates it?

Comment: The output is the same in Chrome, Firefox, Edge. XSLT is running on the server. `xsl:output` method is set to `HTML`. I don't know if my browser manipulates it - it's only my guess.

Comment: I've checked and before browsers manipulates html there is self-closed span tag there: `<span class="A"/>`

Comment: Are you running the XSLT transformation in the browser, or on the server? If on the server, look at the actual file generated before it is sent to the browser.

Comment: @MichaelKay Before beeing parsed by a browser there is self-closed span tag.

Comment: Then we need to know more about how you are running the transformation. Also, generating html in the xhtml namespaces might confuse some XSLT 1.0 serializers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you do not have the correct XSLT output method for HTML as `text/html`, use `<xsl:output method="html"/>` if you want to create HTML to be parsed as `text/html` by a browser. Otherwise the XSLT processor might serialize the empty `span` elements as `<span/>` and then the HTML 5 parsing algorithm indeed turns the sequence of `<span class="A"/><span class="B">foo</span>` into two nested `span` elements, viewable at the "live DOM viewer" for [your example](https://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/?%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0A%3Chtml%3E%0A%3Chead%3E%0A%3Ctitle%3ETest%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%3C%2Fhead%3E%0A%3Cbody%3E%0A%3Cp%3E%3Cspan%20class%3D%22A%22%2F%3E%3Cspan%20class%3D%22B%22%3Efoo%3C%2Fspan%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3C%2Fbody%3E%0A%3C%2Fhtml%3E).

If you have the `xsl:output method="html"` but don't get the right parsing then either you are not letting the XSLT processor serialize the XSLT transformation result or you have namespaces involved.

Based on your edit your XSLT doesn't produce HTML 4 or 5 but rather XHTML (as the namespace declaration `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">` indicates). Do you have any need to do that? For XSLT 1 to produce `text/html` it is much easier to avoid using any namespace for the HTML elements. If you use an XSLT 2 or 3 processor (for instance Saxon 9 can be used under Java) then you can change the output method to `<xsl:output method="xhtml"/>` if you need the namespace but want the result to be parsed as  `text/html` by browsers.

If you need the namespace and need to use XSLT 1 then I would rather suggest to use `<xsl:output method="xml"/>` but then to make sure the browser gets the content as `application/xhtml+xml`, not as `text/html`. But many script libraries using the old `document.write` and other stuff do not work within XHTML parsed as XML so that approach has its flaws, depending on what other resources like Javascript code your result document uses.

Comment: I've added XSLT header to the top post.
I'm using `javax.xml.transform.Transformer` to transform XML.

Comment: @bartex9, see the edit, with the namespace (any namespace) you put on the `html` root the XSLT processor will not use HTML serialization rules for those elements by XML ones.

Comment: Related: you can trick the MS XslCompiledTransform engine into creating close tags for XML by populating with a blank at runtime.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52319211/361842

Comment: @MartinHonnen of course you are rigth. Removing that namespace solved the problem.